# i am not able to use mongo connection url in glue version 4 but it worked fine in glue version 3

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, etl, aws-glue

I have been using aws glue for about a year to extract data from mongo db. i've been using glue version 3. I can perform etl using aws glue version 3 but as soon as i choose glue version 4 and then run the job i get the following error. :

"An error occurred while calling o88.getDynamicFrame. Mongo/DocumentDB connection URL is not supported. Check the Developer Guide for the list of supported data stores/URL formatting"

My code (exact copy from aws glue documentation):read_mongo_options = {
"uri": ""mongodb://:27017"",
"database": "test",
"collection": "coll",
"username": "username",
"password": "pwd"}

dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="mongodb",
connection_options=read_mongo_options)

besides as far as i remember i used to see the "mongodb/documentdb" option in aws glue studio target but i cant anymore.
[image]

I have also tried running crawler and getting the following error message:
[e566adf7-9151-4557-a9d2-236fa24c6e26] ERROR : Test connection failed for connection 'glue_connection_for_mongo'